# Parsing a folder of xml using glob and lxml

Tags: python, lxml, glob

I'm having some difficulty trying to parse a folder of valid xml files `(*.ditamap)` using python 3 and `lxml`.

The error returned is

```
"lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: Document is empty, line 1, column 1"
```

my code

```
import glob
import lxml.etree as et

for file in glob.glob('*.ditamap'):
    with open(file) as xml_file:
        #tree = et.parse("0579182.ditamap")
        tree = et.parse(xml_file)
        print (et.tostring(tree, pretty_print=True))
```

`et.parse` works when i pass a filename directly, but not when I pass the file variable.

What am I doing wrong? Seems like there is a some kind of IO error or tpye mismatch but I cannot see what I am doing wrongly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[et.parse](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.parse) expects a file name but you are giving it an opened file. Try to pass your `file` variable.

```
import glob
import lxml.etree as et

for f in glob.glob('*.ditamap'):
    tree = et.parse(f)
    print (et.tostring(tree, pretty_print=True))
```

You may want to consider using [glob.iglob](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.parse) because you are only using it as an iterator.

Edit: Overread that `et.parse` can accpect file objets. Give it a try nevertheless.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick response! I still get an error however:


    `File "src\lxml\etree.pyx", line 3426, in lxml.etree.parse
    File "src\lxml\parser.pxi", line 1860, in lxml.etree._parseDocument
    File "src\lxml\parser.pxi", line 1880, in 
    lxml.etree._parseFilelikeDocument

    ....

    File "src\lxml\parser.pxi", line 639, in lxml.etree._raiseParseError
    File "C:\Users\jreillai\Desktop\CSV_enrich\0579166.ditamap", line 1
    lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: Document is empty, line 1, column 1`

Comment: Ack. I actually had an empty file in the folder to be processed. all good now.

Comment: If you aren't sure if there are empty / invalid files you should consider checking for those options.